# elasticsearch visualize quotient of two metrics produced by Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How could elasticsearch visualize quotient of two metrics produced by Aggregation?
For example I have the total amount of charge for games and all active users aggregate per day, I want visualize the ARPU (total charge/all active users), what can I do?

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {"query": "*"}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "interval": "1d",
        "time_zone": "Asia/Shanghai",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_pay1": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "pay"
          }
        },
        "sum_active1": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "active_users"
          }
        },
        "ARPU":{
            "bucket_script": {
                "buckets_path": {
                    "sumpay": "sum_pay1",
                    "sumactive": "sum_active1"
                },
                "script": "sumpay / (1.0*sumactive)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how to visualize  ARPU?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in elasticsearch but it can easily be done in Kibana. If u wish to know how to do in Kibana, can write an answer below.

Comment: thanks very mush, I want to know how to do it in Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create a scripted field in Kibana, which will provide you with desired results.

To create a scripted field in Kibana, following the below steps:

- In Kibana, click on Settings tab and then click on your index pattern
- You should see 2 tabs "Fields" and "Scripted fields".
- Click on the "Scripted fields" tab. Then "Add scripted field".
- Enter the "Name" in the Script field as Ratio and  enter the following:-

  doc['pay'].value / doc['active_users'].value

  where pay and active_users are the field name stored in Kibana.
- Click "Create Field" at the bottom. Now your scripted field will be added & can be viewed from Discover page.

Comment: Hi Yuvraj, thanks for your answer, but that's not what I really need, I want the sum(pay)/sum(active_users) aggregate by date, not the sum(pay/active_users), thanks all the same